# Image in jsp through servlet

Tags: image, servlets

I m not able to display image on jsp page plzz help
 dis is my jsp page where d image is to be inserted...`

```
<h4>Welcome<%=rst.getString(1)%></h4>
        <table>
        <tr><td>Designation:<%=rst.getString(4)%></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Date of Birth:<%=rst.getString(8)%>/<%=rst.getString(7)%>/<%=rst.getString(6)%></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Qualification:<%=rst.getString(9)%></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Full Address:<%=rst.getString(10)%><%=rst.getString(11)%></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Contact No:<%=rst.getString(12)%></td></tr
        <tr><td><img src="Image1?imgid=<%=rst.getString(14)%>" width="60" height="60"></img></td></tr>

       </table>
```

and this is my servlet
try
{

```
String  id1=request.getParameter("imgid");
Blob image=null;
byte[]imgData=null;
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connectioncon=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/regf","root","password");  
       Statement st=con.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select image from teac where UserId='"+id1+"'");
```

}

```
    if(rs.next()){
      image = rs.getBlob(18);

               int ln=(int) image.length();       
     imgData = image.getBytes(1,ln);
   response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
              OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();


  InputStream readImg = rs.getBinaryStream(18);
  int index=readImg.read(imgData, 0,ln);  


               response.getOutputStream().write(imgData,0,ln); 
            response.getOutputStream().flush();        
}
```

}

Comment: what value the SRC attribute of <img> will have upon executing above statements. Add more details bro.

Comment: any exception? What is the problem? Have you debugged your code? The db stuff is ok? does it return the blob?

Answer (score 0):

make sure the path "Image1?imgid=<%=rst.getString(14)%>" is correct and follow this format:

```
   <td><img src="" alt="" border=3 height=100 width=100></img></th>.
```

Print this path on the console or on the page and check image exists there.

Comment: ya the path is okay i have checked that the image is stored in database?? i need to retrieve from database

Comment: do you get the right blob from db? can you try storing the retrieved image into a filesystem and check if that is OK? share any exceptions that you might have encountered.